# Изменение заставочной картинки на телефоне Android

Tags: java, android

Возможно ли изменить заставочный экран на телефоне Android программно(на изображение, например)? 
Если да, то как, используя Java.

Comment: Нельзя изменить то, чего не существует.

Comment: Изменил вопрос, извините за неправильную формулировку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Довольно интересный вопрос, и мне кажется что верным ответом на него будет ответ ДА можно. Вот есть способ:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{
    "/system/xbin/su","-c", "cp",
    "/mnt/sdcard/(your folder)/customBootAnimation.zip", 
    "/system/media/bootanimation.zip"});
```

здесь вы будете указывать путь к папке с бутанимацией (я так понял речь идет о ней). Вот есть [первоисточник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996698/programmatically-change-boot-logo-in-android). Это уже совсем программный способ который я не очень уверен что будет работать, потому что я его лично не проверял. Но вообще если есть желание поменять лого загрузки системы то вот например [ссылка](https://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-change-customize-create-android-boot-animation-guide/) где все красиво расписано и все более-менее понятно. Есть куча способов поменять этот экран на то что вам нужно, будь то анимация или просто картинка. Надеюсь хоть чем-то помог в решении вашего вопроса, если возникнут сложности, то не стесняйтесь и пишите, постараемся помочь. Удачи :)